# How to authenticate through java on Office 365?

Tags: java, office365

I am using java and have to transfer some files from my server to an online office 365 Business account, how can I authenticate my remote client? I could not find documentations that do not require .net technologies to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could steal the OAuth part of my Node.js sample here: https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-mail. Look at authHelper.js.